# Custom 404 template file in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-theming, drupal-8

How can I create a custom `404 page` in Drupal 8?

I have created a new page(Content) in the backoffice called `404` (node number 100).
I have set  it as the 404 default page at `Configuration` > 
`Basic site` settings.

[image: Settings]

It works with the content that I have set in the Backoffice.

But now I want it to be editable programatically and I don't know how can I create the overriding file.

I have tried to create `mytheme/templates/html--node--100.html.twig` and it works only when the request its directly that url (`node/100`), but it doesn't work when you try a random slug on the URL and drupal has to resolve it. When this happens, drupal is serving me the content that the `404 page` has in the backoffice and not in the file that I have just created.

I have tried several files like `page--404-html.twig`, `html--node--404.html.twig`, `html--page--404.html.twig`,... but it doesn't work neither

Can anyone lend me a hand?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

page--system--404.html.twig (or the equivalent for other 4xx statuses) no longer works in Drupal 8.3 as the 4xx response handling has changed.  You'll now need the core patch from https://www.drupal.org/node/2363987 or a similar custom module hook that adds template suggestions for these pages:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_page() to set 40x template suggestions
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_page(array $variables) {
  $path_args = explode('/', trim(\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath(), '/'));
  $suggestions = theme_get_suggestions($path_args, 'page');
  $http_error_suggestions = [
    'system.401' => 'page__401',
    'system.403' => 'page__403',
    'system.404' => 'page__404',
  ];
  $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
  if (isset($http_error_suggestions[$route_name])) {
    $suggestions[] = $http_error_suggestions[$route_name];
  }

  return $suggestions;
}
```

EDIT: It's probably nicer to use `hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter` to modify the suggestions array. See an updated version of this code in https://www.drupal.org/project/fourxx_templates (or https://github.com/ahebrank/fourxx_templates/blob/8.x-1.x/fourxx_templates.module)

Comment: This only works as long as you didn't set a custom 404 page in the configuration. At least in my case (Drupal `8.4.4`) `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName()` returns `"entity.node.canonical"`. Any pointers to how to identify and alter the 404 page in such a case?

Comment: It seems in that case you need to do this: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/231652/80492

Comment: I think you should prefer using `HOOK_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables)` otherwise you are overriding `$suggestions` array. It something you probably want to avoid when using, e.g., Context module which provides page templates too.

Comment: @RaphaelLarrinaga, you're probably right. I've updated https://www.drupal.org/project/fourxx_templates to take that into account.

Answer (score 12):

The following implementation adds a template suggestion for page, in this case if you create a page--404.html.twig file in your theme, you'll be able to customize the page and works with Drupal 8.5.1

MYTHEME.theme

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(&$suggestions, $variables, $hook) {
  /**
   * 404 template suggestion.
   */
  if (!is_null(Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->get('exception'))) {
    $status_code = Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->get('exception')->getStatusCode();
    switch ($status_code) {
      case 404: {
        $suggestions[] = 'page__' . (string) $status_code;
        break;
      }
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

and create a template called page--404.html.twig and override with your stuff.

**OR**,
if you want to add suggestions for all error pages, just take out the switch statement.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(&$suggestions, $variables) {
  /**
   * error page template suggestions.
   */
  if (!is_null(Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->get('exception'))) {
    $status_code = Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->get('exception')->getStatusCode();
    $suggestions[] = 'page__' . (string) $status_code;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can now use `page--404.html.twig`. Just be sure you don't set a node as the 404 page. Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/2960810

Comment: You can also use specific preprocess functions for each error code, like:
```function TEMPLATE_preprocess_page__4xx(&$vars) { }```

Answer (score 0):

Try page--system--404.html.twig

Comment: Try to get more details in your answer.  A single sentence will usually be enough.